# elisp create unnamed buffer from contents of file

Tags: elisp

I was trying some code from [Elisp Cookbook](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook#toc42), and I initially tought that this code:

```
 (defun process-file (file)
   "Read the contents of a file into a temp buffer and then do
 something there."
   (when (file-readable-p file)
     (with-temp-buffer
       (insert-file-contents file)
       (goto-char (point-min))
       (while (not (eobp))
       ;; do something here with buffer content
         (forward-line)))))
```

Will create a new ( unnamed/unsaved ) buffer on my emacs window, having the contents of that file ( and maybe open it in the foreground ). However, this doesn't happen. Can you guide me towards this?

EDIT: I experimented a little, and got to this:

```
(defun myTest (file)
    (interactive "f")
    ; check if file is readable
    (when (file-readable-p file)
        ; create a new "untitled" buffer 
        (let ((myBuf (get-buffer-create "untitled")))
            ; make it the current displayed buffer
            (switch-to-buffer myBuf)
            (insert "Hello"))))
```

Is this the way to do it?

Since this is a buffer named "untitled", I can only have one of these in a session. Is there something I could use to have more than one, without resorting to random numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elisp way to generate a unique buffer name is to use `generate-new-buffer-name`.  The documentation is:

```
(generate-new-buffer-name NAME &optional IGNORE)
```

> Return a string that is the name of no existing buffer based on NAME.
>   If there is no live buffer named NAME, then return NAME. Otherwise
>   modify name by appending `', incrementing NUMBER (starting at
>   2) until an unused name is found, and then return that name. Optional
>   second argument IGNORE specifies a name that is okay to use (if it is
>   in the sequence to be tried) even if a buffer with that name exists.